# DataSet Select Where Condition

Tags: asp.net, gridview, dataset

I have a DataSet where I want to be able to have a Select Where Condition based on a search made by the user and bind the data back to the GridView.

```
DataRow[] result = mainData.Tables[0].Select("Last_Name like '%Knitter%'");
```

How do I take this result store it back into a DataSet and bind it to a GridView or how do I bind the DataRow result to a GridView?

Thanks for your help in advance.

### **Update**

Actually I think I got it. All I had to do is:

```
 mainData.Tables[0].Select("Last_Name like '%Knitter%'").CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think I got it. All I had to do is:

```
mainData.Tables[0].Select("Last_Name like '%Knitter%'").CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

```
DataView dv = mainData.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "Last_Name like '%Knitter%'";
gridView.DataSource = dv;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `Encapsulate the logic` at a central location and that part should be reused using `Extension methods`.  Check how `FilterDataTable` is directly being used under `DataTable Class` without inheriting it.

```
public static class GetData
{
    public static DataTable FilterDataTable(this DataTable Dt, string str)
    {
        using (DataView Dv = new DataView(Dt))
        {
            Dv.RowFilter = str;
            return Dv.ToTable();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    using (DataColumn DC = new DataColumn())
    {
        DC.ColumnName = "Abc";
        dt.Columns.Add(DC);

        DataRow Dr = dt.NewRow();
        Dr["Abc"] = "a";
        dt.Rows.Add(Dr);

        Dr = dt.NewRow();
        Dr["Abc"] = "b";
        dt.Rows.Add(Dr);

        using (DataTable Result = dt.FilterDataTable("Abc = 'a'"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```